# How to detect deleted rows when migrating data

Tags: mysql, etl, data-warehouse

I have a main database and am moving data from that database to a second data warehouse on a periodic schedule.

Instead of migrating an entire table each time, I want to only migrate the rows that has changed since the process last run. This is easy enough to do with a WHERE clause. However, suppose some rows have been deleted in the main database. I don't have a good way to detect which rows no longer exist, so that I can delete them on the data warehouse too. Is there a good way to do this? (As opposed to reloading the entire table each time, since the table is huge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done in following steps for let’s say in this example I am using customer table:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   LAST_UPDATED DATETIME,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

1. Create CDC:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS_CDC( 
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   LAST_UPDATED DATETIME,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
   );
   ```
2. Trigger on source table like below on delete event:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER TRG_CUSTOMERS_DEL 
   ON CUSTOMERS
   FOR DELETE
   AS
        INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS_CDC (ID, LAST_UPDATED)
        SELECT ID, getdate()
        FROM DELETED
   ```
3. In your ETL process where you are querying source for changes add deleted records information through UNION or create separate process like below:

   ```
   SELECT ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, LAST_UPDATED, ‘I/U’ STATUS 
   FROM CUSTOMERS 
   WHERE LAST_UPDATED > @lastpulldate
   UNION
   SELECT ID, null, null, null, LAST_UPDATED, ‘D’ STATUS 
   FROM CUSTOMERS_CDC 
   WHERE LAST_UPDATED > @lastpulldate
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you just fire an update query, then it wont update the rows.

The way I see: lets say you have your way where you do a where clause. Youd have that as part of an update query, unless you are doing a csv export. If you do a mysql dump of the rows you wish to update and create a new tempTable in the main database,

Then

```
UPDATE mainTable WHERE id = (SELECT id from tempTable WHERE id >0 and id <1000)
```

If there is no corresponding match, then no update gets run, and no error occurs, by using the id limits as parameters.